# Custom Kong plugin in Lua to handle JWT

Tags: plugins, lua, jwt, kong

I’m learning Lua from scratch, thinking about creating a plugin that works like this:

**Use case 1:**
A website or React app sends a request to kong with NO UserId in a header and NO JWT.
Kong sends the request on it’s way to the intended microservice (guest mode).

**Use case 2:**
A website or React app sends a request to kong with a UserId in a header.
If there are no JWT the plugin will redirect the request to a webpage which creates the JWT and redirects back to Kong, which in turn send the request on it’s way to the intended microservice which uses the JWT.

**Use case 3:**
A website or React app sends a request to kong with a UserId in a header AND a JWT.
Kong send the request on it’s way to the intended microservice which uses the JWT.

I hope I make some kind of sense.
Is this possible to do? Is it hard or easy? Are there already some solution to this out there? If not, I would greatly appreciate some general pointers to how I should go about doing this. I’ve been for programming some time but never touched Lua ^^.

Thanks

Comment: Hey! You might want to post this over at Kong Nation: https://discuss.konghq.com/

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did post there. No responses :/

Answer (score 0):

on you plugin you will implement your logic on access,
on config define header name to retrieve your values and url

check if the value is nil

```lua
function plugin:access(config)
  plugin.super.access(self)
  val = kong.request.get_header(config.headerId)
  jwt = kong.request.get_header(config.headerJwt)
  if val == nil and jwt == nil then -- no ID no JWT guest mode
    return
  end
  if jwt == nil then --case 2 redirect
    kong.response.set_header("Location", config.url)
    return kong.response.exit(302, config.url)
  end
```